# ERROR: relation "foo" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, quoted-identifier

I have a relation called 'serviceID', exist in PostgreSQL DB.
when I run this code

```
select * from serviceID ;
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR:  relation "serviceID" does not exist
```

why?

Comment: Databases consist of tables and columns, not "relations".  The table name is expected after the `from`.

Comment: What does `SHOW search_path;` show? And in which schema is `serviceid`? If it really is a relation, the name suggests it likely is an attribute, could that be?

Comment: I know (table = relation), so I had serviceID table, and it is after 'form'

Comment: it's just a PostgreSQL error @GordonLinoff  i agree its a wierd one... Probably the topicstarter has created the serviceID table with double qoutes in the CREATE TABLE statement if thats that case the query could be `select * from "serviceID"` or `select * from database_name.serviceID`

Comment: ohh, it is work for this  `select * from "serviceID"` why?

Comment: I create this table from sqlalchemy orm models
   `class serviceID(db.Model):`
    `id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)`
    `service_id = db.relationship('Service', backref='service', lazy=True)`

Comment: "Why"? i already give a explainment in mine last comment besides i don't know sqlalchemy

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS "*Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers `FOO`, `foo`, and `"foo"` are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but `"Foo"` and `"FOO"` are different from these three and each other.*"

Comment: Ok anyway, many thanks <3 @RaymondNijland

Comment: Good explanation, thanks @melpomene

Comment: @melpomene That should be an answer :)